# How to put where in relation to method?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Below is my Eloquent query.

```php
$cat = Category::with('subcategory.items.products')
    ->where('id',$discates)->first();
```

I want to put a where on products with `status = 1.`

```
where('status',1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should spend some time reading Laravel docs. They are full of examples and a very good learning resource for the basics.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

```php
 $cat = Category::with(['subcategory.items.products' => function($query){
    $query->where('status', 1);

}])->where('id',$discates)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = Category::query();

$query->whereHas('products', function ($q) {
    $q->where('status', 1);
});


$cat = $query->with('subcategory.items.products')->find($discates);
```

or

```
$cat = $query->with('subcategory.items.products')>where('id',$discates)->first();
```